# Cacti gets data but does not show a graph

Tags: monitoring, cacti, graph, rrdtool

I use Cacti to monitor the call load of a Squire MG1000.
I have created a graph using the SNMP Generic OID template.
In the graph overview, I also see data for current, average and maximum calls but no graph for the calls of the MG1000.
When I create a CSV export of the graph, the exported file is also empty.
It looks like that Cacti stores the data nowhere to create a graph.

[Squire_MG1000_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuQbs.png)

[Graph debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkamU.png)

thanks Sven